# Problems with Texstudio combined with Biblatex/Biber

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, texstudio, biber

enter image description hereI have read almost all of the questions already asked related to my question but did not find the answer that worked for me. I am a Latex newbie and cannot figure out how biblatex works with texstudio.

I changed the bibliography to biblatex. The standard bib tool to biber and in the adnvanced settings the default to biber as well. My texstudio is up to date. My miktex version is the 32bit one (so biber is included).

My bib file is in the same directory as the tex file and I compile with running pdfLatex-->biber-->pdfLatex-->pdfLatex

Here is the result when  run my tex file:

```
\documentclass[pt11,a4paper]{article}
\date{\today{} Vienna}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext}
   \usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,sorting=nyt,natbib=true,hyperref=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Citing.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}


\begin{document}
  test \parencite{kurano_growth_1990,} 


\printbibliography   

\end{document}
```

...and this is the result...
    Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode      "texstudio_xF4620".tex

```
Process exited normally



Process started: biber.exe "texstudio_xF4620"

INFO - This is Biber 2.1
INFO - Logfile is 'texstudio_xF4620.blg'
INFO - Reading 'texstudio_xF4620.bcf'
INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'Citing.bib' for section 0

ERROR - Cannot find 'Citing.bib'!
INFO - ERRORS: 1

Process exited with error(s)



Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "texstudio_xF4620".tex

Process exited normally



Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "texstudio_xF4620".tex

Process exited normally
```

The citations just show the reference key and there is no bibliography at the end of the document.
Is my bib file somehow damaged? Can I repair it somehow?

Thanks already for your answers.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome! What happens if you compile from the command line? Is `Citing.bib` a regular, readable file?

Comment: Sorry for this stupid question but how do I compile from the command line? I just know how to set the commands and the nice shiny green button in texstudio. Citing.bib is a regular file yes.

Comment: It is not a stupid question and, even if it is, I don't know the answer for your system. You are on Windows, I think, which is a frightening and alien world as far as I'm concerned. You want a command prompt or a shell prompt or something like that. But if you don't know, don't worry. There are plenty of Windows users here and somebody will definitely let you know soon. I'm afraid that 'open a terminal emulator' isn't likely to be very useful :(.

Comment: Courtesy of Adam Liter in the chat room: [help is here](http://www.7tutorials.com/7-ways-launch-command-prompt-windows-7-windows-8).

Comment: If you speak German, see 
[Wie kompiliere ich in der Eingabeaufforderung / im Terminal?](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/3461/wie-kompiliere-ich-in-der-eingabeaufforderung-im-terminal) on how to compile from the command line. You need to run `pdflatex texstudio_xF4620`, `biber texstudio_xF4620`, `pdflatex texstudio_xF4620`, `pdflatex texstudio_xF4620`. Can you show us your settings in TeXstudio, maybe you have activated none of the "use build/output subdirectory" features. Also make sure that your `.bib` file lives in the same folder as the `.tex` file.

Comment: Hi! First: you guys are awesome! Love that your answers were so quick. When I run biber on F8 this is the outcome:    Process started:    biber.exe "texstudio_xF4620"

    INFO - This is Biber 2.1
    INFO - Logfile is 'texstudio_xF4620.blg'
    INFO - Reading 'texstudio_xF4620.bcf'
    INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
    INFO - Processing section 0
    INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'Citing.bib' for section 0

    ERROR - Cannot find 'Citing.bib'!
    INFO - ERRORS: 1

    Process exited with error(s)

Comment: I added screenshots of my configuration (the ones that are important I think) :) I will try your other tips and see if those work!

Comment: Ah, seems you are german. Can you check the if the bib-database is in your folder by listing the directory contents? This is also shown in [ Wie kompiliere ich in der Eingabeaufforderung / im Terminal?](http://www.texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/3461/wie-kompiliere-ich-in-der-eingabeaufforderung-im-terminal)

Comment: The screen shots look OK, I couldn't find anything about a build folder. So that doesn't seem to be the problem. Please try running fro the commend line now, so we can check if the error is related to your TeXstudio setup or lies elsewhere. Did you also make sure are files live in the same directory?

Comment: Thanks! Yes german! Btu have no problem with english :) I added screenshots of running it on the command line

Comment: FYI. When running the file with bibtex it somehow works. But I was advised to use biblatex. @Johnnes_B: I will check out that site thanks!

Comment: Lena, there is some corrupted entry in your database. But at least `biber` can find the database. german, well, there is also http://golatex.de/wichtige-hinweise-erstellung-von-literaturverzeichnissen-t11964.html

Comment: Oh my God! I don't know what I did or how.... I just deleted the corrupted file and now it works! Now I just have to figure out why it works with this one and not with my original file (same preamble and all but just different text) :) thank u so much guys! If I have more questions I will ask again!

Comment: Mhhh, does that mean we should close this question, since you cannot reproduce the problem?

Comment: Probably :)! Thanks again guys! U are awesome!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a problem that was apparently resolved by deleting corrupted files.